# Homebrew postgres won't start after uninstall, reinstall and reboot

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I uninstalled and reinstalled postgresql via homebrew. It worked fine until I restarted my computer. Now I'm trying to run my tests and they're blowing up. I'm looking at the current processes and I don't see all those instances of postgres running. I guess I have to turn postgres on. I've tried running

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything (although it does say `server starting`, which is false)

How do I get the server started?

Update. Log info:

```
cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log 
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at the logs. What do they say? Not just `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` but also the logs in `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_log/`.

Comment: posted the server.log. there is no `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_log` directory

Answer (score 8):

Make sure `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` does not exist before starting the server.

On a crash instead of a regular shutdown, this file will remain on disk. It acts as a global lock.

Comment: Please note, I have had to run this every time after my osx machine crashes and leaves the database running in a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't `initdb`'d a database in `/usr/local/var/postgres/`, so there's no `postgresql.conf` or `pg_hba.conf` there. Is it just an empty directory? Or might there be a subdirectory with your DB in it?

If it's empty, then you either have the wrong location for your Pg datadir or you've removed it as part of some prior uninstall and need to create a new DB with the `initdb` command.

Comment: after installing postgres with homebrew it tells me to `If this is your first install, create a database with:
  initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8` when I run this it tells me that the folder already contains `postgres` so I rm -rf what's in there and just run it again. this is then followed by a bunch of confirmation `ok`s. i think my issue might be related to this: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14527

Comment: @NewB no, I strongly doubt that it is related. Your problem is that your data directory is empty or missing. If you do `ls -al /usr/local/var/postgres` what is listed?

Comment: once i updated the kernel, as is suggested in issue14527, and then restarted i was able to start postgres. i'm still afraid to reboot even though i did update the `sysctl.conf`. all seems to be working so far. will update this if it's another epic fail.